# ILT0014: Failed to compile interop source code. See the build log for error details

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to build my UWP app in Release mode. Unfortunately it always raises the same error: `ILT0014: Failed to compile interop source code. See the build log for error details.`. So I tried to repair VS2017, but without luck.

I searched for the error log, but the only thing I could find was `BuildInfo.txt`. [Here](https://pastebin.com/NZYZWfFD) is the content.

I also get a bunch of [warnings](https://pastebin.com/KjJStMz5).

Here is a list of NuGet packages I'm using:

[image]

Comment: As the warnings, it seems you have used some P/Invoke method in your app, please make sure the Apis is available in uwp, see the topic [Win32 and COM APIs for UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps). Besides, what is your app target version and min version?